I need serious help this Windows 7 computer: How do I get to advanced boot options?
I need to go to 'advanced boot options' because I have a problem with my Windows 7 computer that doesn't let me log into my computer.
I saw a video how to fix it, and I have to go to advanced boot options and safe mode but the issue here is that when I follow one of the first steps which is to restart and press the f8 key it brings me to windows recovery and I don't want that! I want advanced boot options!
